# \mathtt font for math, but regular text for text stuff

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to have \mathtt be standard font for math mode, but text just be the default text type.  Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% set up you preferred monospace font here, before mathastext

\usepackage{mathastext}
\MTfamily{\ttdefault}\Mathastext % reload, but use \ttdefault

\begin{document}

I would like to have \texttt{\mbox{\textbackslash mathtt}} be standard font
for math mode, but text just be the default text type. Is there a way to do
this?

\[a^n +b^n = c^n\]

\end{document}
```